# How do I insert data to the row, without lines getting skipped in CSV? in PYTHON

Tags: python, csv

Here's my code:

```
def insert_row():
    import fileinput
    import csv
    sk= raw_input("\nWhat SKU would you like to insert?: ")
    pos= int(raw_input("\nAt what row?: "))

    with open("files.csv","rb") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

    lines.insert(pos, sk)
    with open("files.csv","wb") as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line+'\n')
```

got this with the help of C14l

But there's a problem, when I try to insert it skips lines, this is caused by the '\n', when I tried to delete it, it just concatenated to the string in the position. Is there a way for it to be inserted properly?

Here's the result with my current code inserting "Phillip":

SASA

DA

Phillip
AF

FAF

AD

FAF

FAF

I want it to be:

SASA
DA
Phillip
AF
FAF
AD
FAF
FAF

Any idea how to execute this without skipping line per line? I experimented lots of things here. Can't find out why. i even tried adding another `f.write(line+'\n')`  after the loop hoping it would only add a new line when the loop is done.

making it:

```
for line in lines:
     f.write(line)
     f.write(line+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All lines in your file have a Newline. But your new line from raw_input does not contain a Newline. With your code you add a Newline to every line. Which doubles the Newlines on existing lines and creates the empty lines. Try to only add a Newline to your new line on:
`lines.insert(pos, sk + '\n')`
And change the last line to:
`f.write(line)`

Take a look at the documentation of raw_input():

The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
sk= raw_input("\nWhat SKU would you like to insert?: ")
pos= int(raw_input("\nAt what row?: "))

with open("files.csv","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines.insert(pos, sk + '\n')

with open("files.csv","w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```